# My guitar strings go loose when I tighten them?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, maintenance

I have an [Elevation 3/4 Size Acoustic Guitar](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Elevation-Size-Acoustic-Guitar-Natural/dp/3562000944), as a normal size one is too big for me right now as I'm only 14 and it's my first guitar and money is tight. When I tighten the strings to tune it, the low E string makes a pop sound and goes really loose. I looked at the place where the end of the string sits at the top and saw when it makes the pop sound the tube thing that holds the string jerks back to its original place. I'm just wondering what is doing this and how to fix it? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the gears (cog wheels) in the tuners are slipping, either because they're worn or badly made. Your guitar has open-gear tuners, so you should be able to see what's going on with the one that slips.

Comment: I think we need a proper description term for "the tube thing that holds the guitar" before we can have any idea as to what the problem might be. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @skinnypeacock I guess that was a typo and what was meant was "the tube thing that holds the string". It's a classical-style headstock.

Comment: yeah sorry that was a typo i can see it move back to the place it was before i start tightening when it makes the pop sound anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: It may be that the string is not anchored correctly in the tuning peg, so the string slips when the peg is wound. Look up some youtube videos on how to string a classical guitar.

Comment: i rewired it again correctly and its still doing the same thing

Comment: That's kind of how it goes with super-cheap Chinese guitars. Unless you did something to damage it, this sounds like a defective tuning machine head; if at all possible, you should return it for a replacement or your money back. You could take it to a luthier for a repair, but that would probably cost more than you paid for the guitar in the first place (unless the repair person takes mercy on you: there are some advantages to being 14 ;)) Try @Alphonso's fix first, though....

Answer (score 6):

The screw at the end of the tuning machine can back out and be loose, causing some free play between the gear and the housing, causing slipping when tension is applied.

Try loosening the string until there is no tension on the tuner and then gently tightening the screw at the gear on the peg that is slipping. You may have to wiggle or pull in the post towards the gear to get it to seat.

If the screw does move, continue to tighten it until it seats and then add a little more tightness. Don't over-tighten the screw, if it backs out with use you can tighten it a little more next time.

Sometimes you have to remove the screw and gear and pull the post in towards the tuner before replacing the gear and screw to get it to seat properly.

If the screw is not loose and there is no free play of the plastic string post then it is possible that the tuning machine is faulty.  In some cases I have fixed a gear slipping problem by exchanging the gears between two different posts.

[image: tuning machine assembly]

Answer (score 3):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yx1IG93sEs4) looks like a good guide. Please try installing the strings according to the instructions here and update the question if you still have trouble.

If this does not work for you, it's possible that you have a problem with the actual tuning machine, which is plausible based on this from your question:

> the tube thing that holds the string jerks back to its original place

In that case, it would be worth taking the guitar to a local shop and asking for advice. Most guitar shops are willing to look at issues like this and give good advice.

EDIT: Note that the "handy string winder" is a convenience only - you don't need the electrical one, but the ordinary hand-powered one can be a help.